# Eclipse CDT Code Formatter

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, formatter

Is there a way to force the Eclipse CDT Codestyle Formatter to ignore the blank lines?

As an example we would like to have 2 blank lines between functions in C like the pep8 for python uses

```
// 2 lines between function 
void foo()
{

}


void bar()
{

}
```

But the Formatter removes this blank lines to 1 line for each. So how can i change that behavior.

```
// 1 lines between function 
void foo()
{

}

void bar()
{

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is currently no such option.